# Show the expected length of the constructed confidence interval goes to 0

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

The expected length of the constructed confidence interval is

$2n\theta (\frac{1}{\chi^2_{2n, 0.975}} - \frac{1}{\chi^2_{2n, 0.025}})$ goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

I don't know why the above is true. $\chi^2_{2n, 0.025}$ means the 97.5% quantile. (0.025 is upper tail.)

The solution is below. I don't know where $2n+1.96\sqrt{4n}$ come from.

[image]

Comment: $\chi^2_{2n}$ distribution, with proper scaling and centering, converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution, which implies convergence of the quantile of $\chi^2_{2n}$ (again with proper scaling and centering) to that of $N(0,1)$.

Comment: $1.96$ in the context of a limit of a $95\%$ confidence interval suggests a two-tailed normal, typically related to  the central limit theorem